# rails dispatch event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-engines

First off, I am totally new with `gems` and `engines` (eh. `ruby`);
I am writing a handy `engine` which is going to filter requests based on the `rules` the user(developer) defines, currently my approach is the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action { Acu::Monitor.new request }
end
```

And it works like a charm, but I want the engine to be plug-n-play with minimum configuration by the user, is there anyway I can achive this?
Can I get anywhere between dispatch and controller, where I can validate the request? Is there something like `pre-dispatch-event` in rails?

I would really appreciate if anyone help me on this, I got tired of google this, kind of ran out of query to write! :D

---

#### update:

requests has to be processed, i.e the target controller/action need to be determined by rails then I am processing the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, it is the [instrumentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#rails-framework-hooks) that I was looking for

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "start_processing.action_controller" do |**args|
  # your own custom stuff
end
```

This way `# your own custom stuff` will start to fire before the `before_action`!